# CakePHP Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object, error using the cake javascript helper

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I get a fatal error when trying to use the javascript helper in cakePHP. I am following this [document](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html), I have added jquery to my default layout:

```
<?php 
     <head>
     echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
     ....
     </head>

     <body>
     .....
     echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); // Write cached scripts
     </body>
?>
```

I have also added the helper to my array of helpers in my controller:

```
<?php
     public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Html', 'Form');
```

When I open the page with just these set it is fine and works, however if I add these lines of code to this function and then refresh the page:

```
 public function index()
 {
   ....
   $this->Js->get('#draggable');
   $this->Js->draggable();
 }
```

Cake produces the error Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object.

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try $(document).ready(function(){alert("AA")}); in your webpage. and see whether jquery is loaded or not.

Comment: You should also write `echo $this->fetch('script');` just after the scripts included into your webpage.

Comment: Where is the `index()` method defined? In a controller?

Comment: @dhofstet Yes index is defined in the controller.

Comment: @ArunJain where should I put the fetch, in the layout, view, contoller?

Comment: In the layout just below the echo `$this->Html->script('jquery');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers are meant to be used in views, not in controllers, hence the error. Move the code from your `index()` method to the `index` view and the error should disappear.

Comment: Thanks that has done the job, thank you :) By the way is there any purpose for using the helper in a view instead of using plain javascript in the documet?

Comment: I don't know, I never used the JsHelper myself. I prefer to keep my JavaScript code in separate js files.